How to change an element in one array based on conditions at the same index element in other arrays?
I have two arrays containing 60 0's or 1's. One is defined as result and the other is defined as daysinfected.
The goal is to look at each element of result and set that element to -1 IF it is > 0 AND IF the corresponding element in the daysinfected element is 0.
By printing result for debugging after this code it is obvious that it is not generating -1 values where expected (I.e., where these conditions are both met). In fact it doesn't seem to be modifying anything in result.
for i in range(len(result)):
    for i in range (len(daysinfected)):
        if result[i] > 0 and daysinfected[i] == 0:
            i in result == -1


Your outer loop is redundant here, just this is sufficient:
for i in range (len(daysinfected)):
    if result[i] > 0 and daysinfected[i] == 0:
        i in result == -1

Now, in the 3rd line, i in result == -1 this is an expression, not an assignment. its interpreted like so: (i in result) == -1 where i in result is checking if i exists in result, then you're checking if its equal to -1 with ... == -1, not assigning a value. So really, you want this:
for i in range (len(daysinfected)):
    if result[i] > 0 and daysinfected[i] == 0:
        result[i] = -1 # assign -1 to the i-th value in result, notice the single =

However, with numpy arrays, you should try to avoid looping in python as much as possible. Generally, numpy provides utility functions which can almost always do the trick much faster and are much more readable:
result = np.where((result > 0) & (daysinfected == 0), -1, result)


thanks so much!
I'm brand new to trying to learn python (like less than a week) and while I am making progress I definitely screw up expressions vs. assignments. I type something that reads right, but the syntax is wrong.
Thanks for the info on utility functions. I tried using numpy.where() but I couldn't work it out since I had three conditions and it only takes IF THIS ELSE THAT.

you're welcome :) good luck on learning python! Yea, the numpy.where() takes some getting used to with multiple conditions haha
